# Get data as a JSON format in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, json

I want to build a request endepoints using spring boot: I have to consume restful api and convert that into another rest endpoint.

I have a json Response on www.exampleapiurl.com/details

```
[{
      "name": "age",
      "value": "Child"
  },
{
      "name": "recommendable",
      "value": true
    },

{
      "name": "supported",
      "value": yes
    },
]
[{
      "name": "age",
      "value": "Adult"
  },
{
      "name": "recommendable",
      "value": true
    },

{
      "name": "supported",
      "value": no
    },
]
```

I want the response to be:

```
[{
      "age": "Child"
  },
{
      "recommendable": true
    },

{
      "supported": "yes"
    },
]
[{
      "age": "Adult"
  },
{
      "recommendable": true
    },

{
      "supported": "no"
    },
]
```

For this I have a attribute class with getter and setter:
Attributes.class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) 
public class Attributes {
private String age;
private boolean recommendable;
private String supported;

getter and setter for these:
}
```

This is my service.java class

```
@Service
public class CService {
    private static RestTemplate restTemplate;
    public String url;

    @Autowired
    public CService(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Attributes getAttributes() {

        HttpHeaders headers= new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "some value");
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Attributes.class);
        return response.getBody();

    }
}
```

And this is my controller.class

```
@Controller
public class CController {
    private CService cService;
    @Autowired
    public CController(CService cService) {
        this.cService = cService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/example")
    @ResponseBody
    public Attributes getCAttributes() {
        return cService.getAttributes();    }  

}
```

The Authorization is successful but,
I am not getting any response for now

Comment: By looking at your code, two things I can say at glance.   1)  If you want to recieve the response as type of Attribute, then ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Attributes.class); should be changed as ResponseEntity<Attributes> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Attributes.class);  2) You want a response as an array, but logically your code doesn't return a array

Comment: yes and the responsetype class i am giving here is little bit different.  i want tp give a generic json class and parse that json class and map the attributes accordingly... any idea

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a model class to recive the response from example API
as follows.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Details{
    private String name;
    private String value;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then change your invoking RestTemplate code as follows

```
     Details[] details = null;
//Keeps the example API's data in array.


      ResponseEntity<Details[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Details[].class);
            details = response.getBody();
```

//Next step is to process this array and send the response back to your client

```
    List<Attributes> attributes = new ArrayList<Attributes>();
    Attributes attr = null;
    for(Details detail : details) {
        attr = new Attributes();
       //set the values here 
    }

//returns the attributes here 
attributes.toArray(new Attributes[attributes.size()]);
```